# Compile errors while using shared_ptr with enable_shared_from_this on clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

Consider this piece of code

```
#include <memory>

class FooBar :  public std::enable_shared_from_this<FooBar>{};
typedef std::shared_ptr<const FooBar> ConstantPointer;

int main()
{
  ConstantPointer  p(new FooBar());
  return 0;
}
```

On g++ version 4.7.4 it compiles without problems when using **-std=c++11** option

On clang++ version 
**Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)**

it generates the following compile error

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4013:35: error: no viable overloaded '='
                __e->__weak_this_ = *this;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4050:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::shared_ptr<const FooBar>::__enable_weak_this<FooBar>' requested here
    __enable_weak_this(__p);
    ^
main.cpp:8:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::shared_ptr<const FooBar>::shared_ptr<FooBar, void>' requested here
  ConstantPointer  p(new FooBar());
                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4942:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::__1::shared_ptr<const FooBar>' to 'const std::__1::weak_ptr<FooBar>' for 1st argument
    weak_ptr& operator=(weak_ptr const& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4949:9: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
        operator=(weak_ptr<_Yp> const& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4967:13: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Yp = const FooBar]
            is_convertible<_Yp*, element_type*>::value,
```

My question is if it is compiler bug or non confirming code ?

Comment: Why do you use const in typedef? I think typedef std::shared_ptr<FooBar> ConstantPointer; could be compiled.

Comment: This is the simplest case to which I could reduce my problem. The const might be irrelevant in the attached code but needed in reality.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, clang 3.5.0 (not Apple's) compiles your example, so there seems to be a problem with your specific version or installation of clang.

Secondly, I believe your example is well formed and well defined, because the standard does not specify the exact type parameter of the owning `shared_ptr` instance (`p` in your example):

> [util.smartptr.enab]/7
>
> ```
> shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this();
> shared_ptr<T const> shared_from_this() const;
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `enable_shared_from_this<T>` shall be an accessible base class of `T`. `*this` shall be a subobject of an object `t` of type `T`. **There shall be at least one `shared_ptr` instance `p` that owns `&t`.**